# How to query an Extended Events target file on a SQL Azure Managed Instance by using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm setting up an Extended Events trace in a Managed Instance (**NOT** Azure SQL DB) for the first time.

These are the steps I've carefully followed:

1. Created a Master key on my Database.
2. Created a Database Scope Credential by using the correct Shared Access Signature.
3. Created and started a trace. This works and everything gets traced as expected.

Now, I'm trying to query the XEL file by using T-SQL:

```
SELECT event_data FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file (N'https://whatever.blob.core.windows.net/xevents/MyTrace_132410674100570000.xel',NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

However, I get two different behaviors:

- From SSMS: I just get zero rows and no error or messages displayed.

[image]

- From Azure DataStudio: I get the following error message

[image]

> Msg 300, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 VIEW SERVER STATE permission was
> denied on object 'server', database 'master'. Msg 297, Level 16, State
> 1, Line 1 The user does not have permission to perform this action.

Some facts:

- I'm able to download the XEL file by using Azure Storage Explorer.
- I have already checked the full path to the XEL file and it's correct. I can download the files directly by using a browser.
- The access level of the container is Public.
- I've tried with different files (running and stopped traces, all of them with data).
- The XEL files are full of data since I query them locally and I can open them by using SSMS.
- I really don't think there's a missing key or scoped credential. Otherwise, the tracing would not work. Anyway, I dropped everything and started again from scratch and the behavior did not change.
- All my tests were carried out by using the managed instance administrator account.

So...

- Is reading XEL files really supported on Managed Instances?
- Is there any cath on how to access the files by using the sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right solution, but here's is the workaround that worked for me, in case someone is facing the same issue.

1. I created a small Azure SQL Database (S1).
2. I created a master key for this database.
3. I created a scoped credential pointing to the Azub Blob where the XEL files from the Managed Instance reside in (using the same Shared Signature)

I was able to query by using

```
SELECT event_data FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file (N'https://whatever.blob.core.windows.net/xevents/MyTrace_132410674100570000.xel',NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

It seems like Managed Instance does not support the use of this function (or I wasn't able to find the way to do it).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This may have not been possible at the time that your question was asked, but it currently [supported by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/targets-for-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#sysfn_xe_file_target_read_file-function). I will reproduce their example code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.symmetric_keys
    WHERE name = '##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##'
)
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'REDACTED';

/*
(Re-)create a database scoped credential.
The name of the credential must match the URI of the blob container.
*/
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.credentials
    WHERE name = 'https://exampleaccount4xe.blob.core.windows.net/extended-events-container'
)
DROP CREDENTIAL [https://exampleaccount4xe.blob.core.windows.net/extended-events-container];

/*
The secret is the SAS token for the container. The Read and List permissions are set.
*/
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://exampleaccount4xe.blob.core.windows.net/extended-events-container]
    WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
        SECRET = 'sp=rl&st=2023-10-09T22:12:54Z&se=2023-10-10T06:12:54Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=REDACTED';

/*
Return event session data
*/
SELECT f.*
--,CAST(f.event_data AS XML)  AS [Event-Data-Cast-To-XML]  -- Optional
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('https://exampleaccount4xe.blob.core.windows.net/extended-events-container/event-session-1', DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) AS f;
```

I found that it wasn't necessary to create the master key. I'm also not sure why their SAS token secret only has read and list. You need to create a credential with read, list, and write in order to generate the xel files in the first place. Finally, note this tip from the documentation on how `sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file` should be called differently than usual:

> If you specify a blob name prefix instead of the full blob name in the first argument of sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(), the function will return data from all blobs in the container that match the prefix. This lets you retrieve data from all rollover files of a given event session without using the * wildcard, which isn't supported by Azure Storage.
>
> The previous Azure SQL examples omit the xel extension to read all rollover files for a session named event-session-1.